# How to make OpenGL view and overlaying UIView react to the same touch event

Tags: objective-c, uiview, opengl-es

I have an OpenGL View with sprites in it which have UIViews with the same position and size on top of the OpenGL view, to make them accessible. The OpenGL View should be able to receive touch events and the UIView on top too. In my UIView class I override the hitTest:withEvent method so the UIViews get the touch input, otherwise only the OpenGL gets the touch:

```
-(UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSEnumerator *reverseE = [self.subviews reverseObjectEnumerator];
    UIView *iSubView;
    while ((iSubView = [reverseE nextObject]))
    {
        UIView *viewWasHit = [iSubView hitTest:[self convertPoint:point toView:iSubView] withEvent:event];
        if (viewWasHit)
        {
            return viewWasHit;
        }
    }
    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}
```

Now my UIViews receive touch-input but the OpenGL elements underneath don't. How can I change that so both of them receive the touch.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion in such cases it is best if only your main view receives touches in which you then check if any of the subviews was touched using `CGRectContainsPoint` for instance. If you really want to override the subviews then I suggest you override the touch methods to call the superview touch methods, for instance to override `touchesBegin`:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.superview touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    //do additional stuff
}
```

This will work with touches but probably not with gestures since they cancel touch events and have a different pipeline.